# What factors do you need for a self sustaining cube building

Tags: science-in-society, arcology

In my world, there is the working class, who live in a giant cube called three cubed, there are 27 districts and each are responsible for different things. Three cubed can not only provide for itself, it also supports the upper ruling class that resides on a floating island above the cube, New Eden. However, the Three Cubed is run on an energy source called God's blood, something only located in New Eden.
Assume the technological advancements are well past modern 20th century.

What factors are needed for the cube to work properly?
So far, I've noted down the following

- water treatment
- air treatment
- renewable energy source (New Eden)
- garbage system
- Repair management system (for when the system stops working)

Also as

Comment: Why hasn't research into the needs of modern cities solved this problem? What does looking at, e.g., a list of Los Angeles' city departments and a consideration of the resources needed by the population failed to explain?

Comment: It appears that you have posted the question before typing all of its content. Can you add it?

Comment: I suggest looking into [THE LINE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kz5vEqdaSc). It's an ambitious real world project under development in Saudi Arabia. It's supposed to be an entirely self sustainable city housing millions of people in the middle of the desert. You might get quite some inspiration from looking it up, especially the engineering behind it.

Comment: you appear to be describing some form of Arcology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcology) which, is basically a society in a box; there have been a few experiments in the real world of self contained-self sufficient living arrangements (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosphere_2). without more details, the general answer is going to be along the lines of "what does x real world city need?". Also there is no difference between "tech advancements" and "magic" so you can claim new technology to solve any problem you want as per this description.